# OneSignal - Creating Segments

Tags: api, push-notification, ionic2, onesignal

I want to create Segments in oneSignal with out having to access the dashboard so I was wondering if they have an API for that for or any 
other way to it with me to do it

Answer (score 2):

Currently OneSignal does not have any api for creating segment, but if you want to send notifications to specific group you can use tags.

Yes you can send notification to a particular tag, tags can be used as an alternate to segments.
If you want to send notification to segment A. set tags for that users to {user:A}
and can send notification using this php request.

```
$fields = array(
        'app_id' => YOUR_ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID,
        //'included_segments' => array('plant_a'),
        'filters' => array(array("field" => "tag", "key" => "user", "relation" => "=", "value" => "A")),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );
```

Your complete code will be like

```
<?PHP
    function sendMessage(){
        $content = array(
            "en" => 'English Message'
            );

        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => YOUR_ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID,
            'filters' => array(array("field" => "tag", "key" => "user", "relation" => "=", "value" => "A")),
            'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
            'contents' => $content
        );

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        print("\nJSON sent:\n");
        print($fields);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                                'Authorization: Basic REST_API_KEY'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }

    $response = sendMessage();
    $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    $return = json_encode( $return);

    print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
    print($return);
    print("\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs[https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-segments] you can call de api but you need a ONESIGNAL PAID PLAN

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This can be done via the OneSignal Create Segments endpoint via the REST API ([reference](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-segments)).

Here is an example:

```
    curl -XPOST -H'Authorization: Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY' -H'Content-Type: application/json' https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/segments 
-d '{"name": "1", "filters": [{"field": "session_count", "relation": ">", "value": "1"},{"operator": "AND"}, {"field": "tag", "relation": "!=", "key": "tag_key", "value": "1"},{"operator": "OR"}, {"field": "last_session", "relation": "<", "value": "30"}]}'
```

The response would be something like:

```
// Always true, "id" is uuid of created segment
{"success": true, "id": "7ed2887d-bd24-4a81-8220-4b256a08ab19"}
```